# Add CSS Class to a Form Button

Tags: html, css

I have a button that takes the user back to the previous page and I want to style it using CSS but I want to put this button in its own class so the CSS I write for it does not affect any other buttons on my website.

The current code for the button is:

```
<FORM>
  <INPUT Type="button" VALUE="Go Back To Previous Page" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
</FORM>
```

I have multiple buttons on my page so if I style "button" it will style all of the other buttons.
What I want to do is style only that specific button so i need to add it to it's own class or give it it's own id but unsure how to do this.

Comment: I still don’t get what you’re “unsure” about. If you’re going to do this with IDs, just make sure that all IDs on the page are unique, then put your styling inside `#yourID{`…`}` in your CSS and `id="yourID"` as an attribute on that button.

Answer (score 1):

Due to fact that you want neither to style the button in general nor the input type, I recommend to create a class on your css file.

```
.button-style {your code}
```

Then you can use it as class in your button or input element.

```
<input type="button" class="button-style">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: By the way. If this answer solved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the button and use this id to give it the css you want